# TL074 or TL072 VOL (output voltage swing low)?

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current

TL074 or TL072 VOL (output voltage swing low)?

I can't find it in any datasheet.

I want to know how low the output can get if Vdd=9V and Vss=ground (0V).

If I read the datasheet right, VOH (output swing high) should be at least 6V. Am I correct?

Another really annoying thing is that I can't find a maximum output current.

Can you help? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl072.pdf) provides this information in the Electrical Characteristics table as \$V_{OM}\$, "Maximum peak output voltage swing." The output swing is symmetric. In your case, the output will typically be able to swing between 1.5V and 7.5V, but is only guaranteed to swing from 3V to 6V (for a 10kΩ load).

These amplifiers are really not designed for single-supply operation. If you want the output voltage to be able to swing near 0V, you should select a different amplifier.

Comment: You also need to be aware that TL07xs are prone to latch-up if the output gets too near the negative rail.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the 1st graph on page 11 of [this datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl072.pdf) is that you'll see an output swing of around 1.5V to 7.5V (into a 10k load).
The TL07x opamps aren't really designed for single-supply applications, so you need to read the datasheet with that in mind.
As such, I look at the 4.5V point on the Vcc+/- axis since that's effectively what you're giving it with a single 9V supply.